# Chrome dev tools doesn't appear in electron

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools

I am running a sample Electron.js app on my computer, and it doesn't shows the DevTools nor by clicking on it from the View menu, nor by `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`.

On a friend's computer, the same code is opening it. What can be the setting, that disables this for me?
Here's the code, how I initialize my BrowserWindow:

```
function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  // HERE I AM OPENING THE DEV TOOLS
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}
```

This is were I click, when I want to open it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same kind of symptom : the same app behaved differently on two different computer. I finally solved it by removing the line

```
nodeIntegration: true
```

in main.js, see webPreference block in createWindow

> ```
> function createWindow() {
>   // Create the browser window.
>   const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
>     width: 800,
>     height: 600,
>     webPreferences: {
>       preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
>       nodeIntegration: true
>     }
>   });
> ```

Of course it highlighted some errors that were hidden by this option, but at least I had the dev tools to debug.
I also advice to update electron and chrome to their latest stable version.

Comment: Not working on v16 in my case

Comment: Not working on v18 either